# Reading big data file in python 3

Tags: python

I am new in python. I have got a `.f06` file (nastran output file) and its size approximately 1gb and has got 8m lines. Notepad++ and Textpad cannot open this files. I want to develop a GUI which open type of this files and shows it in a text edit widget. But this operation takes very long time and this situation is not useful for me.

Following part you can see my code.

The text edit widget object name is txtf06.

The form object name is form.

I have two specific boundaries which are 'Grid point force'  and 'MSC.NASTRAN job CREATED'. I want to write all lines between these two boundaries into my text edit widget. It will have approximately 4m lines.

```
def btnImportClickEvent():
    import re
    fileName = form.tbPath.text(): #.f06 path
    file = open(fileName,'r')

    startFilter = "GRID POINT FORCE" #start point
    endFilter = "MSC.NASTRAN JOB CREATED" #end point

    startRegex = re.compile(startFilter, re.DOTALL)
    endRegex = re.compile(endFilter; re.DOTALL)

    status = True

    for i in file:
        searchObj = startRegex.searc(i)
        if searchObj:
        while (status==True):
            form.txtf06.append(file.readline())
            searchObj = endRegex.search(i)
            if searchObj:
                break
        break
    file.close()
```

Comment: Why do you want to load 4m lines into a text editor? Nobody is going to edit that many lines by hand.

Comment: reads very quickly but writing operation takes too long time

Comment: @jan Christoph not for editing, these lines are outputs for my analysis.

Comment: @mrVurucu so you just want to extract the specified part into a new file?

Comment: Your code snippet has several indentation and syntax errors.

Comment: If you want to facilitate interactive exploration, import the data to a database and use an existing SQL client to browse.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file in chunk and use the data for further processing.

See the below example here the file is read in chunks which returns the data in chunks which you can process as per your need.

```
def read_file_in_chunks(filename, chunk_size = 1000):
    with open(filename, 'r')as fp:
        data = "some string to enter in while loop"
        while data:
            data = fp.read(chunk_size)
            yield data

#usage
filename = r"some file path"
for data in read_file_in_chunks(filename):
    print data
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python

You can use this to extract the part between your markers, and then process with further tools (e.g. `numpy` or `pandas`):

```
def extract_between(infile, outfile, start="GRID POINT FORCE", end="MSC.NASTRAN JOB CREATED"):
    with open(infile, 'r') as i, open(outfile, 'w') as o:
        while not start in i.readline():
            pass
        # found start
        # this part could be written nicer with PEP 572
        line = i.readline()
        while not end in line:
            o.write(line)
            line = i.readline()
```

### sed

This gets even easier by using `sed` in a shell like `bash`:

```
sed -n '/GRID POINT FORCE/,/MSC.NASTRAN JOB CREATED/p' infile.txt | sed '1d;$d' > outfile.txt
```

The first `sed` extracts every line between the markers (including the markers), the second `sed` removes the first and last lines (start and end markers).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using wonderful pynastran python libraries by Steve Doyle. They are free and allow you extracting all the data you need directly from op2 (or, but not advised, from f06). Op2 reading is much faster and more complete.